# Remove one tag and all of it's child nodes of a xml using php

Tags: php, xml

i'm trying to remove one item from a xml with all of it's child nodes but when i excecute following php only the child nodes will be removed. 
following is my php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$url = '../../data/auction.xml';
$itemNo ="0";
$xml=simplexml_load_file($url);
    foreach($xml->xpath('/items/item[itemNumber="'.$itemNo.'"]')as $child)
    {
        unset($child[0]);
        //$child->parentNode->removeChild($node);
    }
print $xml->asXML();
?>
```

the original XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
  <item>
    <itemNumber>0</itemNumber>
    <itemName>item1</itemName>
    <category>Phones</category>
 </item>
<item>
    <itemNumber>2</itemNumber>
    <itemName>item3</itemName>
    <category>laptops</category>
   </item>
</items>
```

Actual output

```
<items>
 <item>
 </item>
 <item>
    <itemNumber>2</itemNumber>
    <itemName>item3</itemName>
    <category>laptops</category>
 </item>
</items>
```

Desired output

```
<items>
     <item>
        <itemNumber>2</itemNumber>
        <itemName>item3</itemName>
        <category>laptops</category>
     </item>
</items>
```

Please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: Is the output you've shown the desired output or the actual output? Either way, show both the desired and actual outputs so we know whats happening / needs to happen.

Comment: That code works for me and produces the desired output. [See this example](http://codepad.org/7EMqAr9e)

Comment: Why are you messing about with SimpleXML and unset, if you are using DOMDocument already? Use DOMDocument consistently, simply identify the node you want to remove – and then it’s just one call to removeChild, instead of messy loops.

Comment: For me it never gives the desired. I have the remaining item tags

Comment: I am trying with DOMDocument so far it's not going any where. but don't I have to use foreach there also since i want to check which item I want to remove?

Comment: Works for me: https://eval.in/151930

Comment: Thanx for the help guys since it's not working for me I fixed everything else to work with remaining nodes